# How to transpile TypeScript to ES6 js for node server, then bundle es6.js for client?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, phpstorm

Before migrating to TypeScript, I used to write isomorphic ReactJS code in ES6 and have webpack to handle the bundling for client side using `webpack --watch`. But now with TypeScript in the mix, I'm looking for ways to transpile TypeScript code to ES6 first and then trigger webpack to bundle on file change.

I use PhpStorm, and have tried this method with no success:

First I set up a TypeScript file watcher from PhpStorm to transpile ts scripts and save them in `./type_src/`,

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./type_src/",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "declaration": false

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "type_src"
  ]
}
```

then use `webpack --watch` on `/type_src` folders:

webpack.config:

```
let BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../site/js/build');
let APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'type_src');
let common = {
    output: {path: BUILD_DIR},
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                include: APP_DIR,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react'),
            'react-dom': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-dom')
        },
        extensions: ['','.js','jsx','.ts','.tsx'],

    },
    exclude: [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]

};
```

The TypeScript file watcher is working, but I can't figure out why the webpack fails to trigger even though files in `type_src` have changed by the watcher. Does anyone have suggestions for my situation?

Comment: I think you'll want to remove .ts and .tsx from the `resolve.extensions` key. I think what this is doing is causing it to rebuild on typescript file change *before* the intermediate javascript is generated.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would try to use only one tool.

For example, if you prefer webpack, you can use [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) for processing typescript files.

Or, if you prefer typescript, you can generate single bundle file using `outFile` in `tsconfig.js`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    ....
    "outFile": "bundle.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: but isn't that the bundle produced by webpack not applicable to server side parsing? It will cause some dom undefined error server sides.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to answer without fully understanding of your code. As I understood, you have reactjs components, that use use both on client and server side. Do you have two different js entrypoints for server and client side? If yes, you should use typescript or webpack for them and in the result you will have proper server-side/client-side bundles with same react component codes.

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean. Yes, I'm wrong. I found a [link](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) with some solutions, but it seems a little bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you. I am reading it. Yes, as the article says, I'm looking for a tool that works for both backend and frontend builds. (Compile typescript into one set of es6 scripts for node.js and es5 bundles for client.)